# embed video object in html

Tags: html, flash

I embed a video in html page with swf file. that is running on local host but when i run this on live server. than it dosent work properly.
I link flv video in swf file and embed it in html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','600','height','338','title','testing','src','Edit_video/9vi/home-page2','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','Edit_video/9vi/home-page2' ); //end AC code
</script><noscript><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="600" height="338" title="testing">
  <param name="movie" value="Edit_video/9vi/home-page2.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <embed src="Edit_video/home-page2.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="338"></embed>
</object></noscript>
```

Comment: I'd probably guess your path is wrong, any more clues you can give us?

Comment: I notice straight away that the path to the video is different for the embed and the object tags, the latter has "9vi" in the path... which is correct and which is your browser rendering and where is the SWF really.

Comment: actually i found that my flv path was local.so this prblm mainly creats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> running on local host but when i run this on live server

One reason for that can be careless handling of case.

Windows native filesystems you are case-insensitive, so you can refer to `Edit_video` and if the real name of the directory is actually `edit_video` with a small `e` it doesn't care. But if you then upload it to a server running a case-sensitive filesystem (like most Linux hosts), that won't work any more; the two are different filenames and won't match.

Answer (score 2):

These two urls don't match:

```
<param name="movie" value="Edit_video/9vi/home-page2.swf" />

<embed src="Edit_video/home-page2.swf" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you need to ensure that the file system on your local server matches that of your live server.

I.e. make sure that the file path

> Edit_video/9vi/home-page.swf

is valid from where the HTML is being stored online.